# Is there a bug with the TypeScript compiler regarding generics, or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors

I have come across an issue, which seems impossibly hard to fix. Let's say I have the following code:

```js
interface HasId {
    id: string;
}

type Combiner<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key];
}

function testfn<T extends HasId>(args: Combiner<T>) {

}

class Person<T extends HasId> implements HasId {
    id: string;
    test() {
        testfn<T>({ id: this.id });
    }
}
```

This code is just for example, but there are not supposed to be any errors. However, the problem occurs around this line:

```js
testfn<T>({ id: this.id })
```

It always, always, always throws this error at compile time:

```
Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Combiner<T>'
```

But the thing is, the error is wrong. `{ id: string }` meets the specifications of the `Combiner` type!

Not only that, but on VSCode it suggests that I add the `id` property when I am calling `testfn`, which has led me to believe it's a compiler error.

Am I wrong, or are other people dealing with this error as well?

Edit:

here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "ES2019",
        "lib": ["ES2019"],
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false
    },
    "include": [
        "./src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules",
        "./dist"
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/di1n59 typescript 3.9.2 doesn't have any error? What version of TypeScript are you running?

Comment: @ChauTran 3.9.5

Comment: That's a lot of "always" for something [I can't reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4EkAmyDeAsAFDLLA4BcyGYUoA5gNwkC+JJYAngA4oDCAewC2AI1DQAPABUAfMgC8BEmQDaAawhdyIZJq6CYyaQF1q0jVpMti7YiRgBXEAjDBBuyLRggZsgBRwUAwY1EJiElB+AJQEdiQIADaYGMgACtAYHjLIEAAekCA4qejYOPLAwjyJEMIQ4CWYuMqk5FQ0dIyKyABEPTZkXmD+sUStgxDeIP74bdRgABbAGAB0FMis0QMbbBzEQA).   What gives?

Comment: my current thinking is something around my config setup, as I copied it into an empty folder with that being the only file and it ran fine

Comment: Are you *sure* you didn't mean `testfn<T>({ id: this.id });`?  If so there's definitely a reason why that error shows up (e.g., `new Person<{ id: string, foo: number }>();` is valid, but then `testFn<{id: string, foo: number}>({id: this.id});` definitely doesn't work.

Comment: no I'm sorry I have the wrong code in the question yeah

Comment: And `Combiner<T>` doesn't really seem to do much (it's equivalent to `T` for normal object types) so as example code goes it's kind of weird.

Comment: @jcalz no, because using just `T` requires that you initialize all property values. I'm only looking to use some of them when calling `testfn`

Comment: @ezra your `Combiner<T>` will force you to pass in everything that is in `T`. Not "some of them" like you describe. Does `Partial<T>` not do what you want?

Comment: @ChauTran no, same issue. I thought it was better but apparently not.

Comment: The issue because `{id: asdasd}` does not guarantee to be of type `<T>` when you call `testFn<T>()`. The intention isn't clear enough to say.

Oh and apparently, there's an answer stating the exact thing.

Comment: yes it does, both generic types require `HasId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the following expression:

```
testfn<T>({ id: this.id });
```

It's not guaranteed that the literal value `{ id: this.id }` extends `T`. It does extend `HasId`, but that's not enough.

You might not be dealing with a `Person<HasId>`, but for example with a `Person<{ id: 1, name: 'John' }>` at some point, and that's why the error occurs:

`{ id: this.id }` is not assignable to `{ id: number; name: string }`

If you care about the `id` value only within `testFn`, it should not require the parameterized type `T`, but it could be sufficient to write (which solves the problem):

```
function testfn(args: Combiner<HasId>) {

}
```

But I'm not sure what you intend to do with the `Combiner` type that depended on `T` before.

Comment: I'm not sure, because `testfn` forces `T` to extend `HasId`, so if it doesn't I would have known.

Comment: Yes `T` extends `HasId`, that's exactly why when you call `testfn<T>(...)` that `testfn` expects you to pass a `T`. But instead you pass a `HasId`, and `HasId extends T` is never guaranteed to be true.